# remove specific characters or tags in href by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm editing a WordPress theme.

I have something like this in a WordPress loop:

```
<a class="link" href="<?php the_content(); ?>"></a>
```

Which will turn into something into like this cause by WordPress:

```
<a class="link" href="<p>http://google.com</p>"></a>
```

How do I remove the <p></p> tags inside the href by using jquery? I have multiple of these in a loop.

Comment: I don't know about jquery but if you want to allow only specific tags then you may use wp_kses() or in general for removing all tags you may use htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this very easily without jQuery as well:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
for (var i = 0, j = links.length; i < j; i++) {
    var href = links[i].getAttribute('href');
    href = href.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '');
    links[i].setAttribute('href', href);
}
```